Setting secure setting programmatically
I am creating android app in java. My app is device admin in kiosk mode. I wish to set secure setting (especially back_gesture_inset_scale_left). I tried three below approaches, none of these work. What can I do?
    private static void disableBackGesture1(boolean enabled, DevicePolicyManager devicePolicyManager, ComponentName adminComponentName) {
        try {
            final String value = enabled ? "0" : "1";
            devicePolicyManager.setSecureSetting(adminComponentName, "back_gesture_inset_scale_left"/*Settings.Secure.BACK_GESTURE_INSET_SCALE_LEFT*/, value);
            devicePolicyManager.setSecureSetting(adminComponentName, "back_gesture_inset_scale_right"/*Settings.Secure.BACK_GESTURE_INSET_SCALE_RIGHT*/, value);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    private static void disableBackGesture2(boolean enabled, Context context) {
        try {
            ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
            Settings.Secure.putString(contentResolver, "back_gesture_inset_scale_left"/*Settings.Secure.BACK_GESTURE_INSET_SCALE_LEFT*/, "0");
            Settings.Secure.putString(contentResolver, "back_gesture_inset_scale_right"/*Settings.Secure.BACK_GESTURE_INSET_SCALE_RIGHT*/, "0");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    private static void disableBackGesture3(boolean enabled, Context context) {
        try {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("settings put secure back_gesture_inset_scale_left 0");
            
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                output.append(line).append("\n");
            }
            
            BufferedReader errorReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
            while ((line = errorReader.readLine()) != null) {
                output.append(line).append("\n");
            }
            
            process.waitFor();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

How can I set this setting with out permission exception?
